# JAX-RS PostConstruct / Inject tag in simple GET request project

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jax-rs

I have been deconstructing someone's project which retrieves a response from a 3rd party API and prints it to a Vaadin web GUI.

My version is supposed to retrieve an API response from an anime website, parse this automatically (??) into an object and then print the object attribute to my screen mainly so I can see if it bloody works.

I converted a sample XML file to XSD then used JAXB to generate a class from it (and a builder but I'm not quite sure how that is used yet) in order to store my response from the API.

I have a getservice java class that performs the get request. This worked previously when all I was doing was printing the result of the request to a string and before I tried to put it into an object.

Lastly I have a main JavaApplication4 class that was apparently necessary to create an instance of the request (I'm pretty new to OO programming but it sort of makes sense maybe).

The application runs however I now get an error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javaapplication4.getservice.fetchMovie(getservice.java:36)
    at javaapplication4.JavaApplication4.main(JavaApplication4.java:17)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This points me to the line

```
   return target.queryParam("anime", "4658")
            .request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            .header("Content-type", "text/html")//application_json or text_html or xml
            .get(Ann.class);
```

I used a breakpoint and found that my client and target remain as null both here and on the above lines:

```
@PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        //target = client.target("http://www.omdbapi.com");
        target = client.target("http://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.xml");
}
```

Looking back at the original guy's project, I think the problem is because I am using annotations like @PostConstruct but do not have an @Inject annotation. I tried to add an @Inject to my Main/JavaApplication4 file but it either doesn't do anything (and looks completely wrong) or it tells me its not applicable where I put it.

I would totally appreciate someone to have a quick look and see if its those annotations causing the problem... I don't understand how to use them in any context yet and it is so hard to find examples that do things in a particular way, I am just left trying to reposition bits and pieces for hours and obviously that doesn't work XD

The full code of the project, MINUS the Ann.java class (which should store the API response in the form of anime , title, name, etc etc) and the ObjectFactory.java class which was generated alongside it (and im not sure what it does yet but thats another step):

Ann.java
(getters and setters and xml stuff i think)

ObjectFactory.java

JavaApplication4.java

```
package javaapplication4;

import generated.Ann;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class JavaApplication4 {

//@Inject
//getservice gt;

public static void main(String[] args) {

//@Inject
 getservice gt = new getservice(); 


String output = gt.fetchMovie().getAnime().getName();


System.out.println(output);

}
}
```

getservice.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication4;

import generated.Ann;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 *
 * @author J
 */

@ApplicationScoped
public class getservice {

    private Client client;
    private WebTarget target;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        //target = client.target("http://www.omdbapi.com");
        target = client.target("http://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.xml");
    }

// these apparently stay null when i run JavaAppliation4
// do i need an @Inject somewhere or something completely similar or different?

    public Ann fetchMovie() {
        //return target.queryParam("anime", "4658")
        return target.queryParam("anime", "4658")
                .request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .header("Content-type", "text/html")//application_json or text_html or xml
                .get(Ann.class);
    }
}
```

Thankyou. Its just one of those parts where "i'm stuck so i'll keep trying" doesn't look like its going to get me very far...idk... :)

Comment: A fix has been provided to me! I added  gt.init(); to my main method in order to call the init() method of the gt (getservice) instance in order to force it to function.

Answer (score 0):

@Inject and @Postconstruct relates to "managed beans", CDI. All Java EE servers provide CDI by default. If you wish to use it with plain Java SE environment, you need a CDI implementation like Weld. See [this blog entry](https://randling.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/cdi-in-java-se/) how that can be done.